# Восстановление pickl-а со сторонними объектами

Tags: python, pickle

Сдампил список, содержащий много объектов 3 библиотеки. Когда теперь пробую сделать `pickle.load`, получаю:

> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fields'

Нашёл, что это связано с https://bugs.python.org/issue18359:

> If some class objects have extra arguments in the new constructor ,
> pickle fail to serialize it.

Можно ли как-то всё же прочитать этот пикл, а потом пересохранить в нормальном формате? Проблема в том, что собирать список заново и пиклить очень долго, надо восстановить информацию из этого silently поломонного пикла (никаких предупреждений или ошибок при дампе не было).

Answer (score 0):

Временно добавьте [методы из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) в сторонний класс, загрузите пикл, преобразуйте в нужный формат, а потом удалите.

> In protocols 2 and newer, classes that implements the
> **getnewargs_ex**() method can dictate the values passed to the **new**() method upon unpickling. The method must return a pair (args, kwargs) where args is a tuple of positional arguments and kwargs a
> dictionary of named arguments for constructing the object. Those will
> be passed to the **new**() method upon unpickling.
>
> You should implement this method if the **new**() method of your class
> requires keyword-only arguments. Otherwise, it is recommended for
> compatibility to implement **getnewargs**().